# Try Apache Chemistry CMIS PHP Client

Tags: php, cmis, apache-chemistry

I'm very confused because I've tried to connect to alfresco cmis repository with Apache chemistry PHP library, but when I try from console:

```
php -f cmis_ls.php http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/atom admin admin /
```

I don't receive nothing. Why?

I think, that I've to received a list of all directories in admin personal home, no?

My PHP installation support DOMDocument and curl. But, when I can't try the example of Apache Chemistry CMIS PHP client.

Comment: This site is for programming qusetions. We are not general software tech support.

Comment: Sorry, but I think that my question is a programming question...

Answer (score 0):

You should do like this 
php -f cmis_ls.php http://localhost:8082/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/atom admin admin /Example+Folder 1

This Example Folder is the folder present in my repository. If there are spaces then use "+" and after that you need to pass 1.This 1 is for showing all the array of documents in that folder

From where you are executing this command ?

Well i tried executing this command from alfresco community edition which i installed and also from my apache. I am using ubuntu and it works perfect.

Have you installed maven ?

Have you started the server for alfresco ?

check those things and let me know.Give me screenshot of the error too.

Comment: Sorry Guarav the problem was an alfresco access... sorry for the inconvenience. It's correct all.

Comment: Hello Bro . Its okay 
from where do you get that link  http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/atom . This link worked for me. could you please tell from where did you get it.

And are you aware of this https://github.com/dkd/php-cmis-client 
I founf this repository in github but i dont know how to implement this package . Do you have any idea then do reply.
Its important for me because i am working on it for my company so any help would be appreciated .

Comment: Hi! ... leave an email or something to explain you how to use this github project.  I use the this project in my personal work and it's perfect!

Comment: My email - > gaurav.masand09@gmail.com
Thanks for the reply brother.